# Shapelib.dll does not work properly on Win 64 Platform (Delphi 10.3)

Tags: delphi, dll, shapefile

Shapelib is a library originally written in C, which provides the ability to write simple programs for reading, writing and updating ESRI Shapefiles.

I managed to compile shapelib.dll for 32bit and 64bit on the basis of https://github.com/OSGeo/shapelib and then I wanted to test if that works with the help of ShapeFileII.pas (available in that repo).

I am using Delphi 10.3. I started with Win32 and I wrote simple program which opens .shp file and reads geometry type and coordinates. Everything worked exactly how I wanted.

Then I add Win64 platform and wanted to test it. Unfortunately, program does not work properly on Win64. I can read only geometry type, other info like coordinates etc. are mostly null.

Did someone try to use shapelib library?
Could you give me a hint? Maybe there is some distincion between Win 32/64 data types?

I appreciate any kind of help.

**Update**

To be more precise, I added screenshot covering the same test object on Win32 and Win64. Running on Win32 gives me values just how i want - I need especialy nVertices and padfX, padfY, padfZ. Running on Win64 gives me incorrect value of nVertices (0) and weird one-line displacement (padfX in Win32 is now padfY in Win64).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: *Maybe there is some distincion between Win 32/64 data types?* Yes, of course there are, but there are also types that are the same size in both. You need to do some debugging and check what exactly fails. Then add that to your question.

Comment: We can't help without details, [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Besides eventual 32/64 bit related issues,

> [ShapeFileII.pas](https://github.com/OSGeo/shapelib/blob/master/contrib/ShapeFileII.pas)

That's a 20 years old legacy code.

I would recommend using the free [ArcView ShapeFile OCX and DLL](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=a613e1282404495f8c075dd29ed057a5), instead.

VB6 OCX & DLL, .NET 64bit specific and AnyCPU DLLs are included.

Pascal code snippets used to be included in the library's docs, as far as I remember.

In any case better check the author's repository:

https://github.com/rosspickard/ArcShapeFile

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice. Actually, I already managed to get my program going on Win64 after manipulating datatypes of some variables and changing their size between Win32/64.